# Python modules not found even though installed

Tags: python, pip, package

Python Version: 3.2.3

I've spent hours working on this issue and I'm still scratching my head furiously out of confusion. I'm testing an application built with python in a windows 7 device. I went and installed python and its dependencies. I also installed pip and the following packages: mysql-connector, and mysqlclient. However, when I tried running the script that imports mysql.connector, the debugger returns:

```
import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
```

I went and check the list of packages via `pip list` and saw that the packages we're definitely installed. They are listed as:

```
mysql-connector-python  8.0.26
mysqlclient             2.0.3
```

So, I compared this with my windows 10 device that has the script running without issues and saw that the packages were also installed the same way. I thought there were no issues in the package installation.

However, when I checked the python modules in help("modules"), I found something. The mysql and pip are not listed in the windows 7 device whereas, in my personal device, they were there.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the packages, yet the issue remains. For some reason, python is not able to detect the packages. I also tried to upgrade the pip via `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and as expected, the python can't find the pip. I'm honestly confused at this point. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

It might be worth noting that, since my python version has no pip, I had to install it and copy its path to the system environment variables manually. Could it be connected the source of issue?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: @CameronSima no I am not using virtualenv